# Gráficos de resíduos de um modelo de regressão no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico, plot

Estou tentando transformar dois gráficos de resíduos realizados abaixo em ggplot2.
Como descrição, para realizar estes gráficso, é preciso definir anteriormente algumas funções associadas as especificidades da classe do modelo adotado, as quais, estou disponibilizando a seguir.
O modelo se encontra no argumento `fit`, cujo os dados são da própria biblioteca `nlme`, e os gráficos são plotados ao final do código por meio da função `qqPlot2`.

```
rm(list = ls()); cat('\014')

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
library(splines)
library(gamlss)
library(gridExtra)
library(hnp)
library(car)

extract.lmeDesign2 <- function(m){
  start.level = 1
  data <- getData(m)
  grps <- nlme::getGroups(m)
  n <- length(grps)
  X <- list()
  grp.dims <- m$dims$ncol
  Zt <- model.matrix(m$modelStruct$reStruct, data)
  cov <- as.matrix(m$modelStruct$reStruct)
  i.col <- 1
  n.levels <- length(m$groups)
  Z <- matrix(0, n, 0)
  if (start.level <= n.levels) {
    for (i in 1:(n.levels - start.level + 1)) {
      if (length(levels(m$groups[[n.levels - i + 1]])) != 1)
      {
        X[[1]] <- model.matrix(~m$groups[[n.levels - i +
                                            1]] - 1, 
                               contrasts.arg = c("contr.treatment",
                                                 "contr.treatment"))
      }
      else X[[1]] <- matrix(1, n, 1)
      X[[2]] <- as.matrix(Zt[, i.col:(i.col + grp.dims[i] -
                                        1)])
      i.col <- i.col + grp.dims[i]
      Z <- cbind(mgcv::tensor.prod.model.matrix(X),Z)
    }
    Vr <- matrix(0, ncol(Z), ncol(Z))
    start <- 1
    for (i in 1:(n.levels - start.level + 1)) {
      k <- n.levels - i + 1
      for (j in 1:m$dims$ngrps[i]) {
        stop <- start + ncol(cov[[k]]) - 1
        Vr[ncol(Z) + 1 - (stop:start),ncol(Z) + 1 - (stop:start)] <- cov[[k]]
        start <- stop + 1
      }
    }
  }
  X <- if (class(m$call$fixed) == "name" &&  !is.null(m$data$X)) {
    m$data$X
  } else   {
    model.matrix(formula(eval(m$call$fixed)),data)
  }
  y <- as.vector(matrix(m$residuals, ncol = NCOL(m$residuals))[,NCOL(m$residuals)] + 
                   matrix(m$fitted, ncol = NCOL(m$fitted))[,NCOL(m$fitted)])
  return(list(
    Vr = Vr,                                                                 
    X = X,
    Z = Z,
    sigmasq = m$sigma ^ 2,
    lambda = unique(diag(Vr)),
    y = y,
    k = n.levels
  )
  )
}
fit = lme(distance ~ age, method="REML",data = Orthodont)
data.fit <- extract.lmeDesign2(fit)
data <-    getData(fit)
y <- data.fit$y
X <- data.fit$X
N <- length(y)                                                               
id <-  sort(as.numeric(getGroups(fit, level = 1)), index.return = TRUE)$x   
n <- length(as.numeric(names(table(id))))                                    
vecni <- (table(id))                                                         
p <- ncol(X)                                                                
n.levels <- length(fit$groups)                                               
start.level <- 1
Cgrps <- nlme::getGroups(fit, level = start.level)                           
CCind <- levels((Cgrps))                                                     
sigma2 <- fit$sigma^2
obs <- numeric()

for (i in 1:n)
{
  obs <- append(obs,1:vecni[i])                                               
}
if (n.levels > 1) { 
  lZi <- list()
  lgi <- list()
  numrow <- numeric()
  
  mgroups <- fit$groups      
  for (n in 1:length(CCind)) {
    dgi <- data.frame(as.matrix(mgroups[mgroups == CCind[n], ]))
    nrowzi <- dim(dgi)[1]
    ncolzi <- 0
    girep <- as.numeric(length(levels(dgi[,1])))
    for (k in 2:n.levels) {
      girep <- c(girep,as.numeric(length(levels(dgi[,k]))))
    }
    for (k in 1:n.levels) {
      ncolzi <- ncolzi + as.numeric(length(levels(dgi[,k])))
    }
    auxi <- as.vector(table(dgi[,1]))
    for (i in 2:n.levels) {
      auxi <- c(auxi,as.vector(table(dgi[,i])))
    }
    l <- 1
    Zi <- matrix(0,nrowzi,ncolzi)
    for (j in 1:ncolzi) {
      Zi[l:(l + auxi[j] - 1),j] <- rep(1,auxi[j]) 
      l <- l + auxi[j]
      if (l == (nrowzi + 1)) l <- 1
    }
    
    lZi[[n]] <- Zi
    
    numrow[n] <- dim(Zi)[1]
    
    comp.var <- as.matrix(fit1$modelStruct$reStruct)
    auxg <- rep(as.numeric(comp.var[1])*sigma2,girep[1])
    for (i in 2:length(girep)) {
      auxg <- c(auxg,rep(as.numeric(comp.var[i])*sigma2,girep[i]))
    }
    lgi[[n]] <- diag(auxg)
  }
  q <- dim(lgi[[1]])[1]                     
  for (h in 2:length(CCind)) {
    q <- c(q,dim(lgi[[h]])[1])
  }
  Z <- lZi[[1]]
  for (k in 2:length(CCind)) {
    Z <- bdiag(Z,(lZi[[k]]))
  }
  Z <- as.matrix(Z)
  nrowZi <- lZi[[1]]                        
  for (h in 2:length(CCind)) {
    nrowZi <- c(nrowZi,dim(lZi[[h]])[1])
  }
  
  Gam <- lgi[[1]]
  for (k in 2:length(CCind)) {
    Gam <- bdiag(Gam,(lgi[[k]]))
  }
  Gam <- as.matrix(Gam)
}else{
  mataux <- model.matrix(fit$modelStruct$reStruct,data)
  mataux <- as.data.frame(cbind(mataux,id))
  lZi <- list()
  lgi <- list()
  
  for (i in (as.numeric(unique(id)))) { 
    lZi[[i]] <- as.matrix((subset(split(mataux,id == i,
                                        drop = T)$`TRUE`,select = -id)))          
    lgi[[i]] <- getVarCov(fit,type = "random.effects")
  }
  Z <- as.matrix(bdiag(lZi))
  g <- getVarCov(fit,type = "random.effects")
  q <- dim(g)[1]                                                           
  Gam <- as.matrix(kronecker(diag(length(as.numeric(unique(id)))),g))
}
if (n.levels > 1) {   
  if (!inherits(fit, "lme")) 
    stop("object does not appear to be of class lme")
  grps <- nlme::getGroups(fit)
  n <- length(grps)                                                                     
  n.levels <- length(fit$groups)                                                         
  if (is.null(fit$modelStruct$corStruct)) 
    n.corlevels <- 0
  else n.corlevels <- length(all.vars(nlme::getGroupsFormula(fit$modelStruct$corStruct))) 
  if (n.levels < n.corlevels) {
    getGroupsFormula(fit$modelStruct$corStruct)
    vnames <- all.vars(nlme::getGroupsFormula(fit$modelStruct$corStruct))
    lab <- paste(eval(parse(text = vnames[1]), envir = fit$data))
    if (length(vnames) > 1) 
      for (i in 2:length(vnames)) {
        lab <- paste(lab, "/", eval(parse(text = vnames[i]), 
                                    envir = fit$data), sep = "")
      }
    grps <- factor(lab)
  }
  if (n.levels >= start.level || n.corlevels >= start.level) {
    if (n.levels >= start.level) 
      Cgrps <- nlme::getGroups(fit, level = start.level)                          
    else Cgrps <- grps
    Cind <- sort(as.numeric(Cgrps), index.return = TRUE)$ix                       
    rCind <- 1:n 
    rCind[Cind] <- 1:n
    Clevel <- levels(Cgrps)                                                      
    n.cg <- length(Clevel)                                                         
    size.cg <- array(0, n.cg)
    for (i in 1:n.cg) size.cg[i] <- sum(Cgrps == Clevel[i])  
}
  else {
    n.cg <- 1
    Cind <- 1:n
  }
  if (is.null(fit$modelStruct$varStruct)) 
    w <- rep(fit$sigma, n)
  else {
    w <- 1/nlme::varWeights(fit$modelStruct$varStruct)
    group.name <- names(fit$groups)
    order.txt <- paste("ind<-order(data[[\"", group.name[1], 
                       "\"]]", sep = "")
    if (length(fit$groups) > 1) 
      for (i in 2:length(fit$groups)) order.txt <- paste(order.txt, 
                       ",data[[\"", group.name[i], "\"]]", sep = "")
    order.txt <- paste(order.txt, ")")
    eval(parse(text = order.txt))
    w[ind] <- w
    w <- w * fit$sigma
  }
  w <- w[Cind]
  if (is.null(fit$modelStruct$corStruct)) 
    lR <- array(1, n)
  else {
    c.m <- nlme::corMatrix(fit$modelStruct$corStruct)
    if (!is.list(c.m)) {
      lR <- c.m
      lR <- lR[Cind, ]
      lR <- lR[, Cind]
    }
    else {
      lR <- list()
      ind <- list()
      for (i in 1:n.cg) {
        lR[[i]] <- matrix(0, size.cg[i], size.cg[i])
        ind[[i]] <- 1:size.cg[i]
      }
      Roff <- cumsum(c(1, size.cg))
      gr.name <- names(c.m)
      n.g <- length(c.m)
      j0 <- rep(1, n.cg)
      ii <- 1:n
      for (i in 1:n.g) {
        Clev <- unique(Cgrps[grps == gr.name[i]])
        if (length(Clev) > 1) 
          stop("inner groupings not nested in outer!!")
        k <- (1:n.cg)[Clevel == Clev]
        j1 <- j0[k] + nrow(c.m[[i]]) - 1
        lR[[k]][j0[k]:j1, j0[k]:j1] <- c.m[[i]]
        ind1 <- ii[grps == gr.name[i]]
        ind2 <- rCind[ind1]
        ind[[k]][j0[k]:j1] <- ind2 - Roff[k] + 1
        j0[k] <- j1 + 1
      }
      for (k in 1:n.cg) {
        lR[[k]][ind[[k]], ] <- lR[[k]]
        lR[[k]][, ind[[k]]] <- lR[[k]]
      }
    }
  }
  if (is.list(lR)) {
    for (i in 1:n.cg) {
      wi <- w[Roff[i]:(Roff[i] + size.cg[i] - 1)]
      lR[[i]] <- as.vector(wi) * t(as.vector(wi) * lR[[i]]) 
    }
  }
  else if (is.matrix(lR)) {
    lR <- as.vector(w) * t(as.vector(w) * lR)
  }
  else {
    lR <- w^2 * lR
  }
  if (is.list(lR)) {
    R <- lR[[1]]
    for (k in 2:n.cg) {
      R <- bdiag(R,lR[[k]])
    }
    R <- as.matrix(R)
  }
  else{
    R <- diag(lR)
  }
}else{
  R <- getVarCov(fit,type = "conditional",individual = 1)[[1]]
  for (i in 2:length(as.numeric(unique(id)))) {
    R <- as.matrix(bdiag(R,getVarCov(fit,
                                     type = "conditional",individual = i)[[1]] ) )
  }
}
sqrt.matrix <- function(mat) {              
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)  
  singular_dec <- svd(mat,LINPACK = F)
  U <- singular_dec$u
  V <- singular_dec$v
  D <- diag(singular_dec$d)
  sqrtmatrix <- U %*% sqrt(D) %*% t(V)
}
V <- (Z %*% Gam %*% t(Z)) + R
iV <- solve(V)                                                
varbeta <- solve((t(X) %*% iV %*% X))
Q <- (iV - iV %*% X %*% (varbeta) %*% t(X) %*% iV ) 
zq <- t(Z) %*% Q
norm.frob.ZtQ <- sum(diag(zq %*% t(zq)))
eblue <- as.vector(fixef(fit))
eblup <- Gam %*% t(Z) %*% iV %*% (y - X %*% eblue)
predm <- X %*% eblue                       
predi <- X %*% eblue + Z %*% eblup         
resm <- (y - predm)                        
resc <- (y - predi)  
var.resm <- V - X %*% solve(t(X) %*% iV %*% X) %*% t(X) 
var.resc <- R %*% Q %*% R
ident <- diag(N)
auxnum <- (R %*% Q %*% Z %*% Gam %*% t(Z) %*% Q %*% R)
auxden <- R %*% Q %*% R
CF <- diag(auxnum)/diag(auxden)
rescp <- resc/sqrt(diag(var.resc))
R.half <- sqrt.matrix(R)
auxqn <- eigen((R.half %*% Q %*% R.half), symmetric = T, only.values = FALSE) 
lt <- sqrt(solve(diag((auxqn$values[1:(N-p)])))) %*% t(auxqn$vectors[1:N,1:(N-p)]) %*% solve(sqrt.matrix(R[1:N,1:N]))
var.resmcp <- lt %*% var.resc[1:N,1:N] %*% t(lt)
resmcp <- (lt %*% resc[1:N] )/sqrt(diag(var.resmcp))
 if (n.levels > 1) {
    aux <- Gam %*% t(Z) %*% Q %*% Z %*% Gam
    qm <- q - 1
    dm <- matrix(0,length(CCind),1)
    gbi <- aux[1:(q[1]),(1:q[1])]
    eblupi <- eblup[1:(q[1]),]
    dmi <- t(eblupi) %*% ginv(gbi) %*% eblupi
    dm[1] <- dmi
    for (j in 2:length(CCind)) {
      gbi <- aux[((j - 1)*q[(j - 1)] + 1 ):(q[j] + q[(j - 1)]),((j - 1)*q[(j - 1)] + 1 ):(q[j] + q[(j - 1)])]
      eblupi <- eblup[((j - 1)*q[(j - 1)] + 1 ):(q[j] + q[(j - 1)]),]
      dmi <- t(eblupi) %*% ginv(gbi) %*% eblupi
      dm[j] <- dmi
    }
  }else{
    aux <- Gam %*% t(Z) %*% Q %*% Z %*% Gam
    qm <- q - 1
    dm <- matrix(0,n,1)
    
    for (j in 1:length(CCind)) 
    {
      if (q == 1)
      {
        gbi <- aux[j,j]
        eblupi <- eblup[(q*j - qm):(q*j)]
        dmi <- t(eblupi) %*% ginv(gbi) %*% eblupi
        dm[j] <- dmi
      }
      else
      {
        gbi <- aux[(q*j - qm):(q*j),(q*j - qm):(q*j)]
        cat(gbi,'\n','\t')
        eblupi <- eblup[(q*j - qm):(q*j)]
        dmi <- t(eblupi) %*% ginv(gbi) %*% eblupi
        dm[j] <- dmi
      }
    }
    
  }
qqPlot2 <- function(x, distribution="norm", ..., ylab=deparse(substitute(x)),
                    xlab=paste(distribution, "quantiles"), main = NULL, 
                    las = par("las"),
                    envelope = .95,  
                    col = palette()[1], 
                    col.lines = palette()[2], lwd = 2, pch = 1, cex = par("cex"),
                    cex.lab = par("cex.lab"), cex.axis = par("cex.axis"), 
                    line = c("quartiles", "robust", "none"), 
                    labels = if (!is.null(names(x))) names(x) else seq(along = x),
                    id.method = "y", 
                    id.n = if (id.method[1] == "identify") Inf else 0,
                    id.cex = 1, id.col=palette()[1], grid = TRUE)
{
  line <- match.arg(line)
  good <- !is.na(x)
  ord <- order(x[good])
  ord.x <- x[good][ord]
  ord.lab <- labels[good][ord]
  q.function <- eval(parse(text = paste("q", distribution, sep = "")))
  d.function <- eval(parse(text = paste("d", distribution, sep = "")))
  n <- length(ord.x)
  P <- ppoints(n)
  z <- q.function(P, ...)
  plot(z, ord.x, type = "n", xlab = xlab, 
ylab = ylab, main = main, 
las = las,cex.lab = cex.lab, cex.axis = cex.axis)
  if (grid) {
    grid(lty = 1, equilogs = FALSE)
    box()}
  points(z, ord.x, col = col, pch = pch, cex = cex)
  if (line  == "quartiles" || line == "none") {
    Q.x <- quantile(ord.x, c(.25,.75))
    Q.z <- q.function(c(.25,.75), ...)
    b <- (Q.x[2] - Q.x[1])/(Q.z[2] - Q.z[1])
    a <- Q.x[1] - b*Q.z[1]
    abline(a, b, col = col.lines, lwd = lwd)
  }
  if (line == "robust") {
    coef <- coef(rlm(ord.x ~ z))
    a <- coef[1]
    b <- coef[2]
    abline(a, b)
  }
  conf <- if (envelope == FALSE) .95 else envelope
  zz <- qnorm(1 - (1 - conf)/2)
  SE <- (b/d.function(z, ...))*sqrt(P*(1 - P)/n)
  fit.value <- a + b*z
  upper <- fit.value + zz*SE
  lower <- fit.value - zz*SE
  if (envelope != FALSE) {
    lines(z, upper, lty = 2, lwd = lwd, col = col.lines)
    lines(z, lower, lty = 2, lwd = lwd, col = col.lines)
  }
}

x11()
qqPlot2(resmcp, ylab = "Resíduos", 
        xlab = "Quantil N(0,1)", pch = 20)
qqPlot2(dm, distribution = 'chisq', df = q, pch = 20,
        ylab = expression(paste("Quantis de Mahalanobis")),
        xlab = "Quantis da Qui-quadrado")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha tentativa em reproduzi-los em `ggplot2` foi da seguinte forma:

```
P1 = qqPlot2(resmcp, ylab = "Resíduos", 
        xlab = "Quantil N(0,1)", pch = 20)   
PP1 = ggplot(data = P1, aes(resmcp)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = resmcp), show.legend = FALSE)

P2 = qqPlot2(dm, distribution = 'chisq', df = q, pch = 20,
        ylab = expression(paste("Quantis de Mahalanobis")),
        xlab = "Quantis da Qui-quadrado")
PP2 = ggplot(data = P2, aes(dm)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = dm), show.legend = FALSE)
x11()
gridExtra::grid.arrange(PP1,PP2, ncol = 2)
```

Entretanto, algo está acontecendo, visto que tenho obtido o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por conta do tamanho do seu código, não tentarei implementar uma solução completa pro seu caso. Mas deixo uma indicação: o [pacote qqplotr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=qqplotr) implementa geometrias para gráficos QQ com ggplot2. Por exemplo:

```
library(nlme)
library(qqplotr)

fit <- lme(distance ~ age, Orthodont, method = "REML")

res <- data.frame(residuo = resid(fit))

dist <- "chisq"
dpar <- list(df = 2)

ggplot(res, aes(sample = residuo)) +
  stat_qq_band(distribution = dist, dparams = dpar) +
  stat_qq_point(distribution = dist, dparams = dpar) +
  stat_qq_line(distribution = dist, dparams = dpar, color = "blue")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]